# Javascript file resize

Tags: javascript, webserver, plc, siemens, s7-1200

Recently I was charting live data from simatic s7-1200 plc kit. This plc has a limitation where it only supports 60 KB js files. Is there any link or suggestions where i can get chart.js and jquery-3.1.0.js files which will be under 60KB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Just get minified slim jquery core and minify chart.js with appropriate tools. If .js you need remains above 60KB - you'll need to use other tools because of the limitation.

Comment: slim 3.1.1 is 69K so that would be a limitation right there. Perhaps an older version?

Comment: @Kid Binary
 Can you suggest me any of those tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need small files of **jQuery** and **Chart.js** libraries, here's solution:

**jQuery:**

You have to get slim minified version of [jQuery Core](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/), and additionally gzip it via appropriate tools (`gzip` command can be used in *nix terminal).

If `gzip` is not accepted by pls than you can try to use older versions (some of the are below 60KB) or even [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) package instead of jQuery - the main difference is library file size (way below 60KB).

**Chart.js:**

You can as well try to serve it gzipped, but if you can't, then try to use older version. You can include [this version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js) - old, but below limitation and it supports 6 basic chart types.

---

There are also a workaround, if you can use CDN.